# Regular Expression from String gives null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string

`let str = 'WordA<br>WordB';`

I am using this expression `/(\S+)(?=<br>)/` to match characters before the `<br>`.

It works fine directly as a predefined function

`let regex = /(\S+)(?=<br>)/;`

But when I try to build it using a string, it gives `null` everytime.

```
let rgs = "(\S+)(?=<br>)";
let regex = new RegExp(rgs);
```

How to use the regex as a string to obtain the same results.

Full code:

```js
let str = 'WordA<br>WordB';
let regex = /(\S+)(?=<br>)/;

let m = str.match(regex);
console.log(m);
console.log(m[1]);

let rgs = ("(\S+)(?=<br>)");
let regex2 = new RegExp(rgs);
let m2 = str.match(regex2);
console.log(m2);
console.log(m2[1]);
```

Comment: in other words - you need to escape the escape character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using regex in string via `new RegExp()`, you need to escape the backslash character:

```js
let str = 'WordA<br>WordB';
let regex = /(\S+)(?=<br>)/;

let m = str.match(regex);
console.log(m);
console.log(m[1]);

let rgs = "(\\S+)(?=<br>)";
let regex2 = new RegExp(rgs);
let m2 = str.match(regex2);
console.log(m2);
console.log(m2[1]);
```

Otherwise the `"\S"` is translated to just "S" (as you are escaping the `S` character):

```js
console.log("S", "\S", "\\S", "S" === "\S");
```